# Streaming video from IP Camera to JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx-8, ip-camera

I am running a JavaFX application on a Raspberry Pi that is on the same network as my Wansview NBC540W ip camera. At the moment I simply would like to see the output of the ip camera in the JavaFX application. Any suggestions or working examples?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at this link: https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=wansview you can see that the video stream from that camera is an .asf stream.

Here is some information on streaming in Java applications: [How to play radio live stream .asx video/x-ms-asf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584362/how-to-play-radio-live-stream-asx-video-x-ms-asf)